# Doctrine2 duplicate properties and methods from trait

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, traits

I have an Entity, where I want to use trait "TimestampableEntity" for mapping some properties:

```
namespace Wbudowie\PortalBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Wbudowie\PortalBundle\Traits\TimestampableEntity;

/**
 * Category
 * 
 * @Gedmo\Tree(type="materializedPath")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false)
 * @ORM\Table(name="categories")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category {

    use TimestampableEntity;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
```

This is my TimestampableEntity trait:

```
namespace Wbudowie\PortalBundle\Traits;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

trait TimestampableEntity {

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(name="edited_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $editedAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleted_at",type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deletedAt;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * Sets createdAt.
     *
     * @param  \DateTime $createdAt
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTime $createdAt) {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returns createdAt.
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt() {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Sets updatedAt.
     *
     * @param  \DateTime $updatedAt
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTime $updatedAt) {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returns updatedAt.
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt() {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Sets deletedAt.
     *
     * @param \Datetime|null $deletedAt
     * 
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setDeletedAt(\DateTime $deletedAt = null) {
        $this->deletedAt = $deletedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returns deletedAt.
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDeletedAt() {
        return $this->deletedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Is deleted?
     * 
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isDeleted() {
        return null !== $this->deletedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive) {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getIsActive() {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

}
```

When I run `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities Wbudowie\PortalBundle` on my entity has been added this code:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $createdAt;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $editedAt;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $deletedAt;

/**
 * @var boolean
 */
private $isActive;


/**
 * Set createdAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $createdAt
 * @return Category
 */
public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
{
    $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get createdAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getCreatedAt()
{
    return $this->createdAt;
}

/**
 * Set editedAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $editedAt
 * @return Category
 */
public function setEditedAt($editedAt)
{
    $this->editedAt = $editedAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get editedAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getEditedAt()
{
    return $this->editedAt;
}

/**
 * Set deletedAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $deletedAt
 * @return Category
 */
public function setDeletedAt($deletedAt)
{
    $this->deletedAt = $deletedAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get deletedAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDeletedAt()
{
    return $this->deletedAt;
}

/**
 * Set isActive
 *
 * @param boolean $isActive
 * @return Category
 */
public function setIsActive($isActive)
{
    $this->isActive = $isActive;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get isActive
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getIsActive()
{
    return $this->isActive;
}
```

After that when I try do do anything I'm getting this error, so I have to remove generated code:

> Runtime Notice: Wbudowie\PortalBundle\Entity\Category and Wbudowie\PortalBundle\Traits\TimestampableEntity define the same property ($createdAt) in the composition of Wbudowie\PortalBundle\Entity\Category. This might be incompatible, to improve maintainability consider using accessor methods in traits instead. Class was composed in /mnt/DANE/projekty/wbudowie/src/Wbudowie/PortalBundle/Entity/Category.php line 607

What is wrong? I'm using PHP 5.5.9, Doctrine 2.4.* and Symfony 2.5.*

---

Edit:
It,s doctrine bug. It is fixed, but not in 2.4.x version.

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/632

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/763

Comment: Please write what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I don't want to have copied everything from trait to my entity, because I want to have everything in my trait.

Comment: This patch fix generating entities when you use traits:
http://pastebin.com/bQppqbg5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/timestampable.md)

That's all what you would possibly need to achieve your goal.

And according to [this](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1825), it's something you can't do anything about. Just don't use generate entities :)

Comment: 2nd link is broken. This is precisely why SO policy is to bring the core information of the outsourced data into the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with this. Try these steps:

First add the entity annotation to your trait:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity 
*/
trait TimestampableEntity
```

Temporarily change it to a `class`

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity 
*/
class TimestampableEntity
```

Run `generate:entities` on your trait:

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entities WbudowiePortalBundle:Traits/TimestampableEntity
```

Change `TimestampableEntity` back to a trait:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity 
*/
trait TimestampableEntity
```

Add the trait to `Category`

```
class Category {

    use TimestampableEntity;
```

If you now use:

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entities WbudowiePortalBundle:Category
```

You shouldn't see the duplicates. I'm not sure, but I believe this works because your trait's getters and setters will now be identical to those that might have been created in `Category` so they aren't replaced. Hand coding the getters and settings might cause discrepancies that cause Doctrine to think new code is required in `Category`.